# Convert blob to rtf text using MS Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, blob, rtf

I have table with blob field that contains rtf text. When I'am using

```
select convert(varchar(max),convert(varbinary(max), blob_field)) from my_table
```

It gives me just symbols. How can I convert blob field value to Rtf text?

Comment: Give examples of source rtf-text and result of convertation, please.

Comment: it depends on how you convert your RTF to BLOB :)

Comment: @Indian thats just a text without images. It's coming to database from program.